# libGDX Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(InputForGameScreen); should I make more than one?

Tags: java, libgdx

My game is going to have multiple screens and right now I have one class which is an InputProcessor and a GestureListener. Should I create seperate input classes for each screen and set the screen on show and hide methods or should I just check which screen is active with if branches within the Input class and make one InputProcessor class that handles all the input of every screen?

Comment: define better, multiple screens, is each "screen" a "level" of the game, or are those screens menu screens with one screen being the game itself? or each screen is a viewport and you see all the screens at the same time

Comment: @gia Right now I am still building the basics of the game. Right now I have a main menu screen, a game screen, HUD screen, more will surely come. Actually you are giving me some good ideas for the camera I might have not thought of.

Comment: hah no thanks :P I dont use it anyway. I'll give you a general game programming answer based on my experience, but "whatever works" is a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

When you program games you think on the high level design as the engine, and you separate heavily the engine-logic from the game-logic. If you know MVC for example, then you know how this separating roles of code tends to go.

Have a component that takes input keyboard for instance, but doesn't give it "meaning", just take the data and store it somewhere, this includes analyzing gestures, record the gesture, identify it and store "gesture 'x' received", just liek you stored "key A pressed" or "key A released". That will be the input for the current pass of the game/ui logic.

You should probably have every screen be an object of the game engine, and have the game logic modify them all, but you can separate ui from game logic if you like. In that case, the input will travel to one of them depending on which one is active at the moment (which one has focus).

Each class should have their own way to decode the pre-processed input into specific commands. Because the ui should have common ui components you can have a single library for them all, and then you just inherit from them. If you aren't using common ui objects (butons, scroll panels, panels, text areas, etc), then every screen will have to have its own function for processing input. The ui component receives the input and sends it to the appropriate form object for further work. The game logic will decode and apply stuff on its game logic pass.

As such have different input processors and assign them to the correct screens, give them useful names like MainMenuInputProcessor.

Once you are done you call paint on everything.